# save screenshot on iPad and PC and send it via e-mail (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, ipad, screenshot, unity-game-engine, email-attachments

I'm working on a game. When the user gets to the end, the game should send a screenshot of the screen to a pre-registered e-mail address.
The game does run on iPad and standalone PC. For PC i discovered how to take a screenshot, but it seems not work on the iPad. Any ideas?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

We're using the Prime31 etcera plugin for this.
Easy and fast to implement. 
And I'm not from Prime31 !